# Non-English language papers submitted to REF for evaluation?

Tags: publications, united-kingdom, language, ranking, evaluation

So this is a little U.K. specific - I'm just curious whether any of you have seen or heard about such submissions. Now I'm completely aware that in many disciplines this seems unlikely, but how about in the fields of Arts & Humanities? What was the value of such submissions, if any?

Comment: What does REF stand for?

Comment: Research Excellence Framework

Comment: Not sure, but I doubt it. They would have to find someone to read and evaluate it in the foreign language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non English language outputs are addressed in section 128 of the [REF Documentation](http://www.ref.ac.uk/media/ref/content/pub/assessmentframeworkandguidanceonsubmissions/GOS%20including%20addendum.pdf). Excluding Welsh, for which there was a special system, basically, the output needed to be accompanied by an English language abstract. The abstract is only used to identify an expert capable of evaluating the work and not in the evaluation itself.